# Linked list inserting with two constraints

Tags: c, linked-list, insert

Trying to insert students into a *linked list* alphabetically. students have a name and an age. They are sorted by name and if they have the same name then they are sorted by age.

I can get the name part right but the age is a bit tricky. The part that breaks down is the first if statement. When a new student has the same name as the first person in the list, then they have to be sorted by age but when i try use that code it gives me a segmentation fault. The rest of the code works.
Here is the `code` :

```
Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list)
{
Student* current;

if (list == NULL || (precedes(student->name, list->name) > 0) || strcmp(student->name, list->name) == 0){    
    if (strcmp(list->name, student->name) == 0) {  // goes wrong here i think
        if (student->age < list->age) {
            student->next = list;
            list = student;
        } else {
            student->next = list->next;
            list->next = student;
        }
    } else {
        student->next = list;
        list = student;
    }
} else {
    current = list;
    while(current->next != NULL && (precedes(current->next->name, student->name) > 0)) {
        current= current->next;
    }
    if (current->next != NULL && strcmp(current->next->name, student->name) == 0) {
        if (current->next->age > student->age){
            student->next = current->next;
            current->next = student;
        } else {
            student->next = current->next->next;
            current->next->next = student;
        }
    } else {
        student->next = current->next;
        current->next = student;
    }

}
return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this much, much harder than it needs to be.

You have a stark case where dereferencing a null pointer is definite, and with that so is the ensuring undefined behavior. In your code:

```
if (list == NULL || (precedes(student->name, list->name) > 0) || strcmp(student->name, list->name) == 0){    
    if (strcmp(list->name, student->name) == 0) {  // goes wrong here i think
```

If you enter that if-block due to `list == NULL` being true, you will immediately dereference that null pointer to access its `name` and `age` members. With that comes *undefined behavior* and you're actually *fortunate* your program crashes (it could be worse; it could have succeeded and lulled you into the belief you didn't have a mistake).

---

**Utility Comparison Function**

This task is only complicated by the fact that the comparison of two `Student` objects is *potentially* two-phase rather than one. So do two things:

- Write a comparison function that draws out the specific criteria of less-equal-greater conditions.
- Use that function anywhere you need to compare two `Student` structures.

Such a comparison function would look like this:

```
int cmp_Student(const Student *lhs, const Student *rhs)
{
    int cmp = strcmp(lhs->name, rhs->name);
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = (lhs->age < rhs->age) ? -1 : rhs->age < lhs->age;
    return cmp;
}
```

This returns `< 0` when `lhs` refers to a `Student` that is "less" than `rhs`, zero when `lhs` is equivalent to `rhs`, and `> 0` when `lhs` is "greater" than `rhs`.

Using that, you can then write a simply pointer-to-pointer walk algorithm that walks the pointers in the list looking for a proper insertion point, then uses the pointer-to-pointer to make that happen. This also eliminates the need for special-casing when `list` is NULL, since you really don't care.

```
Student *insert(Student *student, Student *list)
{
    Student **pp = &list;
    while (*pp && cmp_Student(student, *pp) < 0)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    student->next = *pp;
    *pp = student;

    return list;
}
```

Even if you don't do this `insert` approach, you can still use `cmp_Student` for your own algorithm. Regardless, it's worth walking through the above carefully to see how it works, and a debugger is an excellent way to do that.

Obviously you need to fix that null-pointer dereference code path if you stick with your existing implementation, as it is clearly wrong.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer. I have just started coding in C and just this week started using pointers and structs so this information is very helpful. I used your idea of having both constraints in the precedes function and that helped a lot. Didnt end up using pointertopointer as havent been introduced to those yet.